# Cant terminate QProcess running hcitool on linux?

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am trying to use the Linux/Bluez tool: hcitool, to make a BLE scan from QT.

I use the following to open the process:

```
QString program = "sudo stdbuf -oL hcitool -i hci0 lescan";
hcitool = new QProcess();

connect(hcitool, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(hcitool_started()));
connect(hcitool, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(hcitool_finished(int)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(kill_hcitool()), hcitool, SLOT(kill()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(terminate_hcitool()), hcitool, SLOT(terminate()));

hcitool->start(program, QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
```

Then afterwards I continously read from the process to store all the results:

```
QString result = hcitool->readLine();
```

After a couple of seconds, I want to stop the hcitool process, and this is where things goes wrong. I've tried the terminate signal, the kill signal, writing ^C to the process, but nothing works.

Actually the kill signal finishes the process. But not in a good way because afterwards my hci0 is hold up, and I can't start hcitool again before the hci0 has been reset with:

```
hciconfig hci0 down
hciconfig hci0 up
```

So any ideas to how I can terminate this process right?

Comment: If Ctrl-C from console works correctly, to do the same you have to send the SIGINT signal, not SIGKILL.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought happened when sending the terminate signal in QT?.. Can it be because I run hcitool "through" stdbuf?

Comment: `QProcess::terminate` sends `SIGTERM` rather than `SIGINT`.  You could try `::kill(hcitool->processId(), SIGINT)`.  The `stdbuf` *could* be a problem depending on how it handles signals.

Comment: Maybe? You'd have to see through `strace` what's going on. However, another possibility could be just to `close()` the stream, that should give a `SIGHUP`, which may be handled more gracefully.

Comment: Oh! hcitool->close() was the way to go! Great, Thanks! @MatteoItalia want to through an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moving from the comment)

A trick that usually work is to just `close()` the stream, that should give a SIGHUP or SIGPIPE to the child process, which is often handled more gracefully.